# Sessão é destruída após redirect em Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

Desenvolvendo um sistema de login, escrevi o seguinte script no controller:

```
    $usuario = $this->input->post('usuario');
    $senha = $this->input->post('uenha');
    $q = $this->login->logar($usuario, $senha);
    if (!$q):
        $this->session->set_userdata('logado',false);
        redirect('login');
    endif;
    $this->session->set_userdata('logado',true);
    redirect('redacoes');
```

Este é um exemplo.

Acontece que após o redirect para outro controller, as sessões não estão sendo armazenadas.

Obs: Eu carreguei no autoload.

Comment: Sim, estou! Inclusive deixei claro na pergunta. Qualquer sessão que eu declare no controller X e depois redirecione, ou então até acesse manualmente no controller Y, desaparece num toque de mágica..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente da seguinte maneira:

```
$logar = $this->login->logar($this->input->('usuario'), $this->input->post('senha'));

if($logar){
    $this->session->set_userdata('logado', "OK");
    redirect('redacoes');
} else {
    $this->session->set_userdata('logado', false);
    redirect('login');
}
```

Comment: Note o campo senha, na sua questão está escrito `uenha`, pode ser isso?

Comment: Pode detalhar o que há de diferente? até porque o problema não está em meu model, pois o mesmo retorna verdadeiro ou falso corretamente.

Comment: Bastante improvável.. Reescrevi diversas vezes o mesmo código e de repente nessa que escrevi para a pergunta acabei digitando errado.

Comment: Na sua verificação de session, você faz como? if($this->session->userdata('logado')) echo "logado"; ?

Comment: Eu estou restringindo o acesso a página. Mas o problema passa longe da verificação, até porque eu estou deixando um var_dump, e quando atualizo de uma página para outra todas as sessões somem, com exceção da padrão do codeigniter.

Comment: Uhmmmm, o seu retorno dá como verdadeiro?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46803/discussion-between-thiago-barros-and-andre-baill).